# How to update sms status based on twilio status callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sms, twilio

I am using `twilio-ruby` to send messages and I want to update message status in database based on status callback.

Let's say I have `Message` model

```rb
  message = Message.create(body: "Message", status: "pending", to: "+1XXXXXXXXXX", from: "+1XXXXXXXXXX")
```

and I am sending this message via twilio API

```rb
  client = Twilio::REST::Client.new ENV['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID'], ENV['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
  client.messages.create({ from: message.from, to: message.to, body: message.body, callback_url: twilio_callback_url })
```

The problem that in status callback params they only fields by which I can find message is `from` and `to` and there can be many messages with same sender and receiver

[image: 1]

Is there some way to send extra params, like `:message_id` to twilio status callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to add id into the routes

```rb
  # config/routes.rb

  match 'twilio/callback/:id', to: 'twilio#callback', as: :twilio_callback
```

and then pass down the id into `status_callback`

```rb
  client.messages.create({ from: message.from, to: message.to, body: message.body, callback_url: twilio_callback_url(id: message.id) })
```